# 404 error on Vue reload with Caddy; 'try_files {path} /' breaks API

Tags: vue.js, caddy, caddyfile

I'm migrating to my own VPS with mongoDB after having used Firebase and Firebase hosting.

When on example.com/example, refreshing the page results in a 404 error.

Vue.js documentation says to include this in the caddy file:

```
try_files {path} /
```

This prevents the 404 error, but this breaks the api, I guess I somehow need to exclude example.com/api. Does anyone know if this is the case, and what the syntax is?

Also, side question: example.com/api seems to list my entire mongoDB database. Surely this is not desirable, for various reasons? How can I hide this?

Comment: I have the same issue.. did you find a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For hosting just the Vue SPA

```
example.com {
    root * /srv
    encode gzip

    try_files {path} index.html

    file_server
}
```

Ref: https://caddy.community/t/caddy-v2-single-page-app-help-example-rewrites-are-being-weird/9178/2